# Replace the character with two other

Tags: c++, replace, stdstring

I have a `std::string`, how can i replace `:` character with `%%`?

`std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), ':', '%%' );`
this code above doesn't work:

> error no instance matches the arguement list

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to replace all `:` characters in one shot. But you can do it in a loop, like this:

```
string s = "quick:brown:fox:jumps:over:the:lazy:dog";
int i = 0;
for (;;) {
    i = s.find(":", i);
    if (i == string::npos) {
        break;
    }
    s.replace(i, 1, "%%");
}
cout << s << endl;
```

This program [prints](http://ideone.com/t81bWx)

```
quick%%brown%%fox%%jumps%%over%%the%%lazy%%dog
```

If you need to replace only the first colon, then use the body of the loop by itself, without the loop around it.